# How to determine who is trying to access MySql

Tags: mysql

When I check the mysql query logs on our BSD server, I see, repeated again and again:

- 111123  8:23:11      4478 Connect     Access denied for user 'Neohoo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
- 4479 Connect     Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I shut off outside access by adding the skip-networking option and restarting mysql:

cat /etc/my.cnf

- [mysqld]
- // The MySQL server
- skip-innodb
- max_connections=30
- skip-networking
- set-variable=local-infile=0

And verified by:

telnet bsdServer.com 3306
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

The MySql is used with a legacy PHP application. I considered it could be an SQL injection attack but I am at a loss to find which section of the program. The mysql query logs do not show an IP address or any more useful data.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: it's coming from localhost -- they're already on your server, and shutting off networking isn't going to have much effect.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong -- but a SQL injection attack would come from a *trusted* connection.

Comment: @Matt Fenwick: Not sure what you mean by a trusted connection - but its got nothing to do with the source of SQL injection attacks - and and SQL injection attack does not create MySQL connections - it abuses existing ones.

Comment: @symcbean -- that's what I was trying to say, you phrased much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I shut off outside access by adding the skip-networking option

But these users are connecting from localhost - i.e. not across the network.

> The mysql query logs do not show an IP address

Yes they do:

- 111123 8:23:11 4478 Connect Access denied for user 'Neohoo'@'**localhost**' (using password: YES)

Some client running on the machine is trying to connect.

If this machine is running a PHP webserver, particularly one facing the internet, most likely have a PHP code injection issue. Try cross referencing the timestamps on the log entries with your webserver access_log. If you've got the mysql client available on the machine, ensure that your webserver uid can't run it.

Comment: Thanks to all. Looks like I need to learn about PHP code injection.